# NullPointerException on Spring MVC Example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, maven-3

I'm trying to execute an example of MVC application using Spring Framework.

Note that I want to use only Java (no XML).

Note also that I simplified the example, so the view resolver is useless.

This is the project's structure:

[image]

This is the **POM.xml** file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <groupId>it.unipi.ing.ciampi</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestMVCSpring</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestMVCSpring Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <dependencies>

    <!-- SERVLETS + JSP + JSTL -->
    <!-- Dependencies for Servlets  -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies for Jstl -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies for Servlet-Jsp api -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END SERVLETS + JSP + JSTL -->

    <!-- SPRING FRAMEWORK -->
    <!-- Dependencies for Spring Core -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies for Spring Web MVC -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END SPRING FRAMEWORK -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Configuration of the maven-compiler-plugins to use Java 1.8 -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Definition of the tomcat7-maven-plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <path>/</path>
          <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>TestMVCSpring</finalName>
  </build>


  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </properties>

</project>
```

These are the implemented classes:

**WebConfig**

```
    package it.unipi.ing.ciampi.testmvcspring.configuration;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.unipi.ing.ciampi.testmvcspring")
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        /*
         * Definition of a view resolver
         */
        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

            return resolver;
        }
    }
```

**WebAppInitializer**

```
package it.unipi.ing.ciampi.testmvcspring.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;



public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

**TestController**

```
package it.unipi.ing.ciampi.testmvcspring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestControler {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String home() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Then I use mvn clean install command, finally mvn tomcat7:run command.
But when I try to visit my localhost:8080 address, I have this error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ott 12, 2016 11:00:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ott 12, 2016 11:00:32 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
```

**UPDATE**
It seems that the problem was the pattern where the dispatcher was listening to. By the way, I am confused about that.
I initially created a Maven Project, so the WEB-INF folder was in src->main->webapp->WEB-INF.
Then I've updated the Project Facets changing the version of the Web Dynamic Module to 3.0 . Eclipse has added a new folder, Web Content, under which there was another WEB-INF folder. 
I delete the webapp folder and now, at the address localhost:8080/ , my dispatcher is active.
Is it the correct solution? Where can I set the path where the dispatcher will be listening to?

Comment: i run your code and it works fine. But i do not use maven, hence maybe the problem is in the library your are including in your pom. Have you tried removing the first three imports? They aren't necessary.

Comment: First dependency is necessary....therefore the error is already here...

Comment: Could you tell me how you have executed the code, please?

Comment: I copied your classes and put Spring libraries in my WEB-INF/lib folder. The difference is i use liberty profile as application server. Try accessing your application throw this url:  localhost:8080/TestMVCSpring/ (the name of your project after localhost)

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide jsp page so that i not sure to get your issue completely. But it seems you are wrong when you use JRE System Library with JavaSE-1.8. You should change it to JDK 1.8 then compile the porject again.

I found it in the post [Creating Spring MVC Project in Eclipse Using Maven](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/creating-spring-mvc-project-in-eclipse-using-maven.html)

Hope this help!

Comment: I use @ResponseBody Annotation, so page.jsp is useless. I also try to comment the viewResolver, but I have the same error

Comment: I think that the problem isn't related with Java, it compiles successfully